# Subtracting times taken from a .csv in python

Tags: python, excel, csv, python-2.7

```
    elif row[inc3].startswith('LIGHT ON'):
        onstr = row[inc3 + 1]
        onlst.append(onstr)
    elif row[inc4].startswith('LIGHT OFF'):
        offstr = row[inc4 + 1]
        offlst.append(offstr)

for idx, val in enumerate(onlst):
    tdifflst.append(float(offlst[idx]) - float(onlst[idx]))
```

Here I pulled out the code from a script that extracts data from an EXCEL spreadsheet and analyzes it. The two types of values are the time a light turned on and the time a light turned off. For instance light on at 0500 and light off at 2300.

I want to subtract the on time from the off time but I obviously can't treat these as true floats because of the 60 minutes to an hour thing. How do I treat these "floats" like the times they are?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a string like `'0500'` to a float? Because you can just do `float('0500')` and that will yield the correct float 500.0 because float conversion ignores 0s in strings. Sorry if this is not what you are asking. I am somewhat uncertain.

Comment: Not quite what I was asking. See the first answer by elyase and my comment on it.

Comment: You've tagged this with `[excel]` which suggests Excel is involved in some way, but you don't say how. Is the data entered in Excel and saved as CSV? Or do you start with a native Excel file (`.xls` or `.xlsx`) which you then *convert* to CSV (perhaps using Python)? Who is entering the data? Your comments to various answers suggest you can decide how the data is entered (2500 vs. 0100 for example). If so, then why aren't you using Excel's dates and times (as suggested by PyNEwbie)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> light_on = datetime.strptime('0500', '%H%M')
>>> light_off = datetime.strptime('2300', '%H%M')
>>> print light_off - light_on
18:00:00
```

`light_on` and `light_off` are datetime objects and the difference is a [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object.

Comment: I upvoted this but honestly as a newbie I hate these answers because they really don't address my specific problem.  That is the correct code should be light_on = datetime.strptime(onstr,%H%M)  With your answer I have to figure that out and I am already lost - that is why I posted the question in the first place

Comment: Here's a curveball: Will this work if I, say, left the light on til 1AM the next day? In the EXCEL sheet, I wrote it as "2500" but that can be changed.

Comment: @SciurusDoomus, Yes, but then you also have to specify the day so that Python can know if you refer to 1AM from the previous day or the next, the format would change to `'%d%H%M'`.

Comment: So would I indicate 100 or 2500?

Comment: @SciurusDoomus, Can the lights be on for more than 24 hours? For example from 0500 to 0700 from the next day(i.e. for 26 hours)?

Comment: Yes. There are several instances where the lights were on for 25 hours.

Comment: @SciurusDoomus Then I recommend you to write it so: `010500`(5am from day one) and `020100`(1am from day 2) and use the format `'%d%H%M'`. This will get you a 20 hours difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are at least implying that the time will always be reported in the form hhmm

therefore it is trivial to modify your code

```
elif row[inc3].startswith('LIGHT ON'):
    raw_time = row[inc3 + 1]
    hour = raw_time[0:2]
    minute = raw_time[2:]
    minute_hour_fraction = int(minute)/60.
    str_time = ''.join([hour,str(minute_hour_fraction)[1:]])
    float_time = float(str_time)

    onlst.append(float_time)
elif row[inc4].startswith('LIGHT OFF'):
   same as above
```

Comment: This seems like it would work if I called 1AM the next day "2500." Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but I actually think you can get better by using the Excel's date-time features/expressions  but that will take a little more work.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
import datetime

hh, mm = int(offstr[0:2]), int(offstr[2:4])
# a dummy date 101/1/1
toff = datetime.datetime(101, 1, 1, hh, mm)

hh, mm = int(onstr[0:2]), int(onstr[2:4])
tdiff = toff - datetime.timedelta(hours=hh, minutes=mm)

tdiff.hour
tdiff.minute
```

Also you can add the whole date (year, month, day) to the datetime objects, so you can get the result for difference greater than 24 hours.